# Android N not playing ringtone?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I upgraded my Nexus 6 to Android N via a fresh flash. No OTA update.

When my activity opens, this code should run the alarm:

```
if (alarm.getSound() != null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, alarm.getSound().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    tone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, alarm.getSound());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        AudioAttributes aa = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setFlags(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM | AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        tone.setAudioAttributes(aa);
    }
    tone.setStreamType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    tone.play();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "NO ALARM SET", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I get the toast with the media URI but nothing plays. The logcat doesn't seem to have anything in it relating to ringtone at all, neither success nor failure. I've double checked the volume several times.

It does play in the emulator but not no my device. What's going on?

Comment: What sort of `Uri` is `alarm.getSound()` returning?

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't have it up right now, but it was the full `media://content/.../11` url that accurately pointed to a ringtone. Mysteriously it started working again over the last couple of days. I've made no changes to the app other than the toast to show the url.